# Cannot use implements with Javas' built in Integer

Tags: java

I am trying to run the code generated from an OpenAPI and as dumb as it sounds I am trying to create an interface to implement the Integer class.
My code:

```
package io.swagger.client.model;
public interface TS29571CommonDataYamlcomponentsschemasDurationSec implements Integer(){
}
```

The error I get after running it:

```
/home/***/Desktop/java-client-generated/java-client-generated/src/main/java/io/swagger/client/model/TS29571CommonDataYamlcomponentsschemasDurationSec.java:[3,82] '{' expected
```

I am fairly new to Java so I believe I make an obvious mistake I am too untrained to find.

Comment: Is it the built-in Java wrapper class you want to implement? If so, it won't work - it's a class and you can only implement interfaces. Also, your syntax must be as follows: "implements Integer" without the brackets which are a constructor call

Comment: Despite having answered this, I'm pretty sure this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). What are you **actually** trying to do? Whatever it is you are trying to solve, I'm pretty sure it's not going to be solved by having a class extend or implement `Integer`.

Comment: @ChrisNeve - I'm not trying to be the language police or nitpick, I genuinely think this is important, but you need to be a little more precise. It's the 'parenthesis' that need removing -- there are no brackets there (brackets are used for arrays). On a multi-cultural site we must communicate as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: you don't need paranethesis after the class name, i.e. it would be just `implements Integer {` which is why the compiler says `{` expected: it literally was waiting for a `{` when you put a `(` there.

Second: `Integer` is not an interface, but a class. As such it can't be implemented. It also can't be extended (which would be next similar thing to attempt), because it is `final`.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate answer! I tried it without the () but I had the same error. I this case could I try copy paste the source code of the Integer class to my new class in order to recreate it?

Comment: You probably could copy the source code of `Integer` into another class and it would probably even compile (maybe with some minor modifications) but as I commented on your question: this almost **certainly** won't solve your underlying problem. If you could tell us **why** you think you need your own personal `Integer` implementation, we could suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: I am trying to recreate a VNF and the 3GPP org had given some simple data types like the Duration in Seconds (this particular question) the equivalency of Integer. It would be much easier for my code to have the given class Name from the 3GPP in this case TS29571CommonDataYamlcomponentsschemasDurationSec as an integer than finding this name and changing it through all my generated codes.

Comment: The easiest way is to make this class be a very simple wrapper around a single `Integer` instance instead (or maybe even an `int`, if `null` isn't a desirable value). Also, that name sounds to me like it describes a *property* or *field* or *variable* and not a whole type, but that might depend on the details of what you've been given.

Answer (score 0):

The error message refers to the incorrect syntax of

```
..implements Integer() {
```

Which would correctly be:

```
..implements Integer {
```

Except of course a java Integer is a class not an interface and you extend classes not implement them. Integer is also final so you can't even extend it and even if you could you almost certainly shouldn't.

Comment: You cannot extend `Integer`, it is `final`.